# Crew for Stack V1.0! (full native client)

Tags: app

[image]

---

[App link](https://apps.apple.com/it/app/crew-for-stack-overflow/id1547171709?l=en) (https://apps.apple.com/it/app/crew-for-stack-overflow/id1547171709?l=en)

---

Crew is a beautiful full native (iOS) **StackOverflow** app built for fast navigation with powerful set of features.
The delightful interface is coupled with extensive features that feel part on your device, whilst elevating your **Stack Overflow** experience.

It’s created specifically with iOS design guidelines in mind, so it fits right at home on your device.

Browse question without distraction or ads, use filter, add comments, or visit specific website areas like tags profile or badges section.
You can quickly view list, tabs, inbox, notifications and more using gestures and context menu.

**Crew** is an unofficial app, and side effects may include an incredible browsing experience.

---

EXCITING FEATURES:

- Trends and search support
- All questions,answers and comments from Stack Overflow in your hands.
- Search support
- Rich rendering of questions
- Dark mode
- Beautiful iOS centric Ui
- Universal app for iPhone and iPad.
- Compose question with real time previews.
- Powerful question filters (month, week, votes and more)

---

It’s constatly evolving. If you have anything you’d specifically like to see, come to the Settings section and text me, I’d love to hear it!