# Crew for Exchange 2.0 (Full iOS native client)

Tags: app, api-v2.2, stackapps, ios

[image]

My all-new app Crew 2.0 is NOW AVAILABLE

Crew 2.0 was rebuilt entirely from the ground up, and today's update is a crazy one.
A completely revamped user interface, powerful markdown rendering, new app customizations, and 382+ StackExchange channels.

That's right. 382+ Stack Exchange channels will now fit in your pocket.

Crew is coupled with extensive features that elevate your Stack experience.

AppStore link: https://apps.apple.com/it/app/crew-for-stack-overflow/id1547171709?l=en

I would love any feedback or review!

---

Previous post (I've lost the account) => [Crew for Stack (full native client)](https://stackapps.com/questions/8839/crew-for-stack-full-native-client)

Comment: Welcome back - please use the [Contact Us](/contact) form to have your accounts merged, to regain full control over your posts.

Comment: Good work so far! Let me know if there’s a better place to submit feedback in the future.

- The home page with list of sites has its own listing of searchable posts separate from the search page. I think these 2 pages should be combined, or the home page could switch to the search page after the site is selected.
- Post content wider than the viewport is not cureently visible, either by horizontal scroll or changing zoom/sizing.

Comment: It looks like links to other stack exchange content opens in a browser, but the app should instead check the host in the url or something to route within the app.